# Code has to do one thing first, then wait a couple of seconds, then continue

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm making a memorygame and I want, when 2 cards are clicked, that they turn around again and sho their backs. As you can see in my code, I'm counting the clicks and when "NumberOfCLicks" hits 2, the "resetCards" method is called. It does what it's supposed to do, turning both cards, but won't show the front of the second card first before turning them again.

My code:

```
public class MemoryGrid
{
    private Grid grid;
    private int rows, cols;

    public MemoryGrid(Grid grid, int rows, int cols)
    {
        this.grid = grid;
        this.rows = rows;
        this.cols = cols;

        InitializeGrid();
        AddImages();
    }


    private void InitializeGrid()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
        {
            grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
        }
    }

    private void AddImages()
    {
        List<ImageSource> images = GetImagesList();
        for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++)
            {
                Image back = new Image();
                back.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/images/back.png", UriKind.Relative));

                back.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventHandler(CardClick);

                back.Tag = images.First();
                images.RemoveAt(0);
                Grid.SetColumn(back, col);
                Grid.SetRow(back, row);
                grid.Children.Add(back);
            }
        }
    }



    static int numberOfClicks = 0;
    private Image card;
    static int score;
    private Image Image1;
    private Image Image2;



    private void CardClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Image card = (Image)sender;
        ImageSource front = (ImageSource)card.Tag;
        card.Source = front;
        numberOfClicks++;

        checkCards(card);
    }

    private void checkCards(Image card)
    {

        this.card = card;
        if (numberOfClicks < 2 || numberOfClicks == 2)
        {

            if (this.Image1 == null)
            {
                Image1 = card;
            }
            else if (this.Image2 == null)
            {
                Image2 = card;
            }
        }

        if (numberOfClicks == 2)
        {
            checkPair();

            numberOfClicks = 0;
            Image1 = null;
            Image2 = null;
        }
    }

    public void checkPair()
    {
        resetCards(Image1, Image2);
       // more code here to check if the 2 cards are a pair.
       // First only a reset after 2 cards.
    }

    private void resetCards(Image card1, Image card2)
    {
        this.Image1 = card1;
        this.Image2 = card2;


        card1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/images/back.png", UriKind.Relative));
        card2.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/images/back.png", UriKind.Relative));
    }

    public List<ImageSource> GetImagesList()
    {
        List<ImageSource> images = new List<ImageSource>();
        List<string> random = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {

            int imageNR = 0;

            Random rnd = new Random();
            imageNR = rnd.Next(1, 17);
            if (random.Contains(Convert.ToString(imageNR)))
            {
                i--;
            }
            else
            {
                random.Add(Convert.ToString(imageNR));
                ImageSource source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("images/" + imageNR + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
                images.Add(source);
            }
        }
        return images;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand the case correctly without building and running the sample app, the sequence is:

click first card - everthing is fine

click second card:

- it shows front (`card.Source = front;`)
- perform `checkCards`
- perform `checkPair` because `numberOfClicks == 2`
- perform `resetCards`, and card shows back image **very quickly**. front image wasn't noticed

introduce some delay before showing back image:

```
private bool hasDelay;
private async void resetCards(Image card1, Image card2)
{
    this.Image1 = card1;
    this.Image2 = card2;

    hasDelay = true;
    await Task.Delay(2000);

    card1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/images/back.png", UriKind.Relative));
    card2.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/images/back.png", UriKind.Relative));
    hasDelay = false;
}
```

don't process clicks while there is delay!

```
private void CardClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (hasDelay) return;

    Image card = (Image)sender;
    ImageSource front = (ImageSource)card.Tag;
    card.Source = front;
    numberOfClicks++;

    checkCards(card);
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to use the [Thread.Sleep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.sleep?view=netframework-4.7.2) method:

```
Thread.Sleep(2000);
```

But I would recommend you to working with [Tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netframework-4.7.2). This gives you an asynchronous process and the interface does not freeze. Then you could do something like this:

```
    public static async Task TaskMethod()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Start Waiting");
        Task t = Task.Run(() => DoSomething() );
    }

    private static void DoSomething()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        Console.WriteLine("Wake up !");
    }
```

Comment: Task.Delay() not invented here. Also `async` method without `await` inside is a) not really asynchronous or b) indicates programming error

Comment: @ASh that's true.This was just an example of how asynchronous methods can be used for

Comment: This is an example how not to do things

Answer (score -1):

If the code just has to wait and do nothing when the second card is shown, you could simply use the `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);` command. The '1000' you see means it will wait for 1 second. 2000 would be 2 seconds and so on. This command simply prevents the next step from happening for the given amount of time. I hope this helps!

Good luck!

Edit: I've just been told this does not work. Sorry!

Comment: @ASh That's true, but wouldn't it work if you put Thread.Sleep() right after the UI updates?

Comment: No, UI code is event-driven and should use a Timer rather than sleeping

Comment: @Ash ah, I didn't know that. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.